# How to convert pdf file into binary in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I filled the pdf using pdf_forms gem , now i want to convert that pdf into binary and want to send via email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to convert a pdf to binary to attach it to an email.  just add this line inside the method of your mailer

`attachments["filename.pdf"] = File.read("/path/to/filename.pdf")`

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want to send the pdf as an attachment.  The official Rails ActionMailer has an example on how to do this

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = user_url(@user)
    attachments['terms.pdf'] = File.read('/path/terms.pdf')
    mail(:to => user.email,
         :subject => "Please see the Terms and Conditions attached")
  end
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-attachments